# How to initiate a 2 way SMS conversation between to validated phone numbers

Tags: twilio

We have the need to open an SMS conversion between clients and service providers. The thought is to send an initial request to the provider with a message from the client and then have the provider reply (and converse) directly with the client.
I've looked in the quick starts and the API docs but I don't see any clear pathway. 
Am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a product like Twilio Conversations for that purpose. You add both as participants into a conversation. They communicate to each other via their assigned Twilio Proxy numbers.

[Introducing Twilio Conversations: Now, every message becomes an invitation for a conversation](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-twilio-conversations)

[Using Twilio Conversations (Using Conversation You Tube Video - Signal 2019)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pkQ6dSvTlo)

Comment: Thank you.  I like the idea of the using the proxy numbers but are they persistent? In other words, can a client reach their provider at any time?

Comment: Yes, until you delete the participants from the conversation.